# How to install webacula 7 on centos 7

Tags: centos, installation, bacula

this is a tutorial to install webacula 7 (after bacula 7 with mysql)

this is the tutorial for centos+bcula that i used (without webmin section)
http://www.backupcentral.com/phpBB2/two-way-mirrors-of-external-mailing-lists-3/bacula-25/howto-install-bacula-7-on-centos-7-fresh-install-126395/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Then to install webacula:

yum install httpd php php-mysql php-gd

wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/webacula/webacula/7.0.0/webacula-7.0.0.tar.gz?r=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Fwebacula%2F%3Fsource%3Dtyp_redirect&ts=1429012567&use_mirror=garr
(download webacula 7.0.0)
yum install httpd php php-mysql
tar -xzvf /root/webacula-7.0.0.tar.gz\?r\=http...

mv webacula-7.0.0 /var/www/
mv /var/www/webacula-7.0.0/ /var/www/webacula


chown -R root.root .
chown apache.apache cache
groupadd bacula
usermod -aG bacula apache
chgrp bacula /usr/sbin/bconsole
/etc/bacula/bconsole.conf
chgrp bacula /etc/bacula/bconsole.conf
cd ../application


nano config.ini 
update:
bacula.bconsole    = "/usr/sbin/bconsole"
bacula.bconsolecmd = "-n -c /etc/bacula/bconsole.conf"

nano /etc/sudoers
comment:
# Defaults requiretty

nano /etc/bacula/bconsole.conf
update:
Password = "YOUR PASS"

nano /etc/selinux/config
update:
SELINUX=disabled


nano /etc/sudoers.d/apache
add:
apache ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/bconsole

reboot (because the selinux)

check with this command:
su -l apache -s /bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/bconsole -n -c /etc/bacula/bconsole.conf"

normal respons :
Connecting to Director localhost:9101
1000 OK: 1 bacula-dir Version: 7.0.5 (28 July 2014)
Enter a period to cancel a command.
*quit





cd /var/www/webacula/install/apache/
cp webacula.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/webacula.conf
nano /etc/httpd/conf.d/webacula.conf
update:
Alias /webacula  /usr/share/webacula/html
<Directory /usr/share/webacula/html>
...
Deny from all

to:
Alias /webacula  /var/www/webacula/html
<Directory /var/www/webacula/html>
...
Allow from all



nano /var/www/webacula/application/config.ini
update your db pass


nano /etc/bacula/bacula-dir.conf
update :
catalog = all, !skipped, !saved


cd /var/www/webacula/install
./password-to-hash.php your bacula webming pass

take ther respons and put in:
nano db.conf
update:
db_pwd="your root mysql pass"
....
webacula_root_pwd="your res from ./password-to-hash.php"

cd MySql/
./10_make_tables.sh
./20_acl_make_tables.sh


systemctl restart httpd

add Zend to webacula:
cd /var/www/webacula/library
wget https://packages.zendframework.com/releases/ZendFramework-1.12.3/ZendFramework-1.12.3-minimal.tar.gz (download only ver 1.12.3!!!!!!)
tar -xzf ZendFramework-1.12.3-minimal.tar.gz
mkdir Zend
cp -Rf ZendFramework-1.12.3-minimal/library/Zend/* Zend/.

go to website :)

now we finished but for me the root password did not work, so to fix this i did:
mysql -uroot -p
use bacula;
update webacula_users set email='your email here';

go to website and reset password
```